# How to create/Delete sheet without changing old sheets for .xls files?

Tags: python-2.7, xlrd, xlsxwriter

I have tried to create new sheet using xlsxwriter.add_worksheet() but Its changing my old sheets.Any library which can create a new sheet without effecting other sheets and How can i delete sheet in .xls file because I didn't find any function in xlrd or xlsxwriter which can delete a sheet.

Edit:1 Tried using win32 module. Able to delete the sheet but unable to create new sheet without effecting existing sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Found the answer

**Creating a new sheet** :

```
import xlrd
xl_ref = xlrd.open_workbook('Path to file')
```

Here type(xl_ref) is <**class 'xlrd.book.Book**> So when we call function

```
xl_ref.add_sheet('Test1')
```

There got the error book object has no attribute.So basically whenever we want to manipulate .xls file without affecting existing changes.first, convert into workbook object.

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
xlwb_ref=copy(xl_ref)
xlwb_ref.add_sheet('Test1')
xlwb_ref.save('Path to file')
```

Reference: [Python_doc](http://pythonhosted.org/xlutils/copy.html)

**Deleting Sheet** :

```
    import pythoncom
    from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch
    pythoncom.CoInitialize() #if Calling same thing again and again so better reinitialize. 
    excel = EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("Path to file")
    sheet = excel.Sheets("Sheet name")
    sheet.Delete()
    excel_file.Close(True)
```